# Searching the list in not functioning in Android

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` and I want it to implement search functionality:

Here is my code in my `MainActivity` class:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);        
adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(Companieslist.this, mStrings,company_name, company_website);                                     
list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

originalValues = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String , Object> temp;
int nb = company_name.size();
for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    temp.put("name", company_name.get(i));
    temp.put("url", mStrings.get(i));    
    temp.put("website", company_website.get(i));
    //add the row to the ArrayList
    originalValues.add(temp);        
}
searchResults = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>(originalValues);
searchlist.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Companieslist.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);                           
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

The custom adapter to my `ListView` is the following:

```
//Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener 
public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    private Activity activity;
    private List<String> data,names,company_website;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    private List<String>filteredData = null;
    private List<String>filteredimages = null;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, List<String> d,List<String> n, List<String> cw) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        names = n;
        this.filteredData = n ;
        this.filteredimages = data ;
        company_website=cw;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Create ImageLoader object to download and show image in list
        // Call ImageLoader constructor to initialize FileCache
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements
    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView text;
        //  public TextView text1;
        //   public TextView textWide;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null) {
            // Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below )
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            // View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //  holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

            // Set holder with LayoutInflater
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(names.get(position));

        //  holder.text1.setText("company description "+position);
        ImageView image = holder.image;

        // DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), image);

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),Register.class));
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),company_website.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {}

    // Called when Item click in ListView
    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Companieslist sct = (Companieslist)activity;
            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }               
    }   

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }


    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String>list = names;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData =  (List<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Suffice it to say, the search functionality isn't working.  There is no filtering at all and the `ListView` remains the same.  Does anyone know what's wrong?